# Lapply function in R do not perform the function

Tags: r, list, dataframe, time, lapply

I try to perform an operation over all the data frames inside of a list using lapply function of R

[image]

This is the operation where I try to subset each data frame by deleting the data of the last year if it is incomplete. This is the lapply function:

```
df_split3 <- lapply(df_split2, function(x) ifelse(length(x$year[x$year==tail(x$year,1)])<365, x <- subset(x, x$year < tail(x$year,1)),x <- subset(x, x$year <= tail(x$year,1))))
```

The output I got is incomplete
[image]

I know the function works when I do out of the lapply function:

(This code works)

```
x <- df_split2[[1]]
    ifelse(length(x$year[x$year==tail(x$year,1)])<365, x <- subset(x, x$year < tail(x$year,1)),x <- subset(x, x$year <= tail(x$year,1)))
```

What Am I doing wrong applying lapply?

Comment: Your use of `ifelse` is wrong. Very wrong. I suspect you intend to use `if` and `else` which are a control flow construct but `ifelse` isn't that.

Comment: Thank you @Roland, I have corrected it!